# Laravel 5 JSON / Blade

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass a JSON to my view

With this code:

```
  Route::get('json', function() {
    $path = storage_path() . "/json/dish.json"; 
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
    return View::make('pages.json')->withJson($json);
  });
```

With `{{dd($json)}}`

I receive this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "dish" => array:297 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▶]
1 => array:2 [▶]
2 => array:2 [▶]
3 => array:5 [▶]
...
```

When I try to display the content of my `$json` with:

```
@foreach($json["dish"] as $key => $item)
  {{$item}}
@endforeach
```

I get this error message:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /Users/beyerdynamic/Documents/Developer/dev1/resources/views/pages/json.blade.php)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$item` is an `array`.

Comment: 0 => array:2 [▶] apparently $item is also an array

Answer (score 2):

By default Laravel tries to escape any variables before input. If you want to avoid it use `{!! $item !!}`. However, $item is array and it will not help you to show proper values. You will get 'Array' as output. If you want to display correct data use `{{ $item['your_key'] }}`.

Comment: My JSON file contains key like this 
 "dish": [
  {
   "title": "California Burger",
   "body": "Beefburger mit geschmolzenem Cheddar Cheese, Salat, Tomaten und Zwiebeln",
   "price": "7,90 €",
   "vendor": "Schräglage",   
  },
  {
   "title": "Lammkeule",
   "body": "aus dem Ofen mit Bratensoße, dazu Reis, dazu Beilagensalat und Fladenbrot",
   "price": "8,50 €",
   "vendor": "Taverna Sultan Saray",
  }] I am not sure how to itterate trough each key like (price, vendor,title,body) in my view. How can I access the "title", "body" keys?