# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given, Json_decode ;

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have problem. I can't print value of `$value->working` type unicode in foreach but that not working and i have notification `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`
I'm using Json. When i echo `dd($levelResult)` then

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "Đại Học"
]
```

if i echo `$levelResult[0]` then i have notification `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
@foreach( $search as $key => $value)
    @if(json_decode($value->working,JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)[0] != " ")           
         @foreach(json_decode($value->working) as $key => $levelResult)
               <p>{{ $levelResult }} </p>               
         @endforeach
    @else
      {{ " " }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 JSON / Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206896/laravel-5-json-blade)

Comment: Possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39206896/laravel-5-json-blade/39206988#39206988

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov: if i echo $levelResult[0] then i have notification Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

To fix your second issue use `json_decode($value->working, true)` to parse json in array but not in object.

I would suggest you yo use the following code snippet. The code will parse json once and proper if comparison.

```
@foreach( $search as $key => $value)
    <?php $result = json_decode($value->working, true, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING); ?>
    @if($result[0] != " ")
        @foreach($result as $key => $levelResult)
                   <p>{{ $levelResult[0] }} </p>
        @endforeach
    @else
      {{ " " }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: i will testing :D

Comment: @Andreyj Ludinovskov: i used code of you but i still see notification 

`htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
at htmlentities(array('Đại Học'), '3', 'UTF-8', false) in helpers.php line 531` i don't know why it's not working :'(

Comment: @BiHíp does it make sense to check $result[0] != " " if it's array always?